# Django-allauth templates missing from site-packages

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-allauth

I installed allauth. all up and running correctly etc but now i want to customise my forms I cannot find the allauth templates inside my site-packages.

Wondering if there is a step I missed during installation to make sure these are available?

Comment: do you want to customize your forms or HTML templates?

Answer (score 0):

By default you cannot modify the template, it is installed your virtual environnement, however from the [Allauth documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html) it says:

> For instance, the view corresponding to the account_login URL uses the
> template account/login.html. If you create a file with this name in
> your code layout, it can override the one shipped with allauth.

So it is as easy as creating the correct folder and file and then you will be able to extends and modify what you want.

[Customise the form in allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#account-forms)